# quaternion composition in geometric algebra

Tags: quaternions, geometric-algebras

I was studying the book Linear And Geometric Algebra and I've been stuck at this problem for couple of days.

Assume $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and two quaternions $q_1$ is a rotation of $90^\circ$ around $e_3$ and $q_2$ is a rotation of $90^\circ$ around $e_1$.

$$\mathbf{I} = e_1e_2e_3$$
$$q_1 = e^{-e_3\mathbf{I}45^\circ}$$
$$\quad q_2 = e^{-e_1\mathbf{I}45^\circ}$$

Now calculate the composition $q_2q_1$.  The answer in the book is:

$$cos60^\circ-\dfrac{e_1-e_2+e_3}{\sqrt 3}\mathbf{I}\,sin60^\circ$$

But I couldn't figure the steps to get there.

This is what I can do so far,

\begin{align}
q_2q_1 &= (cos45^\circ - e_1\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ)(cos45^\circ-e_3\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ) \\
       &= cos45^\circ cos45^\circ-e_1\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ cos45^\circ-e_3\mathbf{I}\,cos45^\circ sin45^\circ + e_1\mathbf{I}e_3\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ sin45^\circ \\
       &= cos45^\circ cos45^\circ-e_1\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ cos45^\circ-e_3\mathbf{I}\,cos45^\circ sin45^\circ + e_2\mathbf{I}\,sin45^\circ sin45^\circ
\end{align}

How do I proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}e^{-e_1I\pi/4}e^{-e_3I\pi/4} &= \big(\cos(\pi/4)-e_1I\sin(\pi/4)\big)\big(\cos(\pi/4)-e_3I\sin(\pi/4)\big) \\
&= \frac 12\big(1 -e_3I-e_1I+e_1Ie_3I\big) \\
&= \frac 12\big(1 -e_3I-e_1I+e_2I\big) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{e_1-e_2+e_3}{2}I\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{e_1-e_2+e_3}{\sqrt{3}}I\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \\
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \frac{e_1-e_2+e_3}{\sqrt{3}}I\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\end{align}$$